# about java use oracle to operate images

Tags: java, transactions

I am not using SSH to do my project.First,I insert a `empty_blob()`,then update it.But when I invoke `executeUpdate()`,other process seem to insert a new record.My sql `max(no)` would select the wrong record. And how can I use the transaction in a transaction?

```
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    pstm = conn.prepareStatement(ADD_SQL);
    pstm.setString(1, brand.getName());
    pstm.setString(2, brand.getDescription());
    pstm.setString(3, brand.getAddress());
    pstm.executeUpdate();

    pstm = conn.prepareStatement("select * from brands where no=(select max(no) from brands)        for update");
rs = pstm.executeQuery();
```

Comment: What does SSH have to do with anything?

Answer (score 0):

Something to do with your transaction isolation level.

You do not need where no=(select max(no) from ....

I assume you are using a sequence to populate 'no' and need to return that newly inserted value.

```
insert into foo(no, name,description, address)
values(seq_no.nextvalue, ?,?,?);
returning no into ?
```

then

```
...
pstm.registerOutParameter(4,TYPES.NUMBER,0);
pstm.executeUpdate();
int newNo=pstm.getInt(4);
```

Comment: I don't think Oracle supports the returning clause outside of PL/SQL.

Comment: I am gald that you answered my question.But I can't find a method called registerOutParameter(). Fortunately,I find out a easy method to solve it.First 'select sequence.nextval from dual' and then insert the record.My English is poor,thank for your answer.

Comment: I am so eager to know how to do a transaction in a transaction.I just know the 'conn.setAutoCommit(false)' to perform a transaction .

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the last generated sequence value, you have two options:

You can use seq_name.nextval after running the insert statement (e.g. `SELECT my_sequence.nextval FROM dual;`)

If your column is populated using a trigger, you can use the JDBC API to retrieve the generated value:

```
pstm = conn.prepareStatement(ADD_SQL, new String[] { "NO"} );
...
pstm.executeUpdate();

ResultSet rsNo = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next())
{
   long id = rs.getLong(1);
   System.out.println("The generated value was: " + id);
}
```

Comment: I am gald that you answered my question.But my roacle not supports the feature method getGeneratedKeys(). Fortunately,I find out a easy method to solve it.First 'select sequence.nextval from dual' and then insert the record.My English is poor,thank for your answer.

Comment: I am so eager to know how to do a transaction in a transaction.I just know the 'conn.setAutoCommit(false)' to perform a transaction .

Comment: The Oracle driver (at least any up-to-date version) **does** support getGeneratedKeys(). Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: I try what you guide me to do.As a result,the exception which api explains the unsupported feture occured.

Comment: Then you need to upgrade your driver from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html Anything with a version greater than 10.x should do.

Comment: Thanks to you,can you tell me about what I should do to perform a transaction in a transaction by using java.I just know the connection's method setAutoCommit(false) to perform a transaction.

Comment: I am so excited that I hava solved the problems puzzling me for a long time.Thanks,best wishes to you!